# Constructing NSStrings on the fly, mos effecient way

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get coordinates from GPS, need to build a small string that looks like this :

```
      NSString *location = @"40.7,-73.9";
```

MY code right now is

```
       NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [LocationFinder    
                                singleton].location.coordinate.latitude];
       NSString *longtitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [LocationFinder 
                                singleton].location.coordinate.latitude];
       // Of course this doesn;t work
       NSString *location = latitude, logtitude;
```

Now I know I can do the NSMutablestring and append, but I just wanted to aks ehether there is a very effecient ay of doing this process. Coming from .NET and Java I hate Obj C for this weirdness it has.

Comment: You can use `stringWithFormat:` with more than 1 argument, @"%f, %f"

Comment: Yeah, just use stringWithFormat the same way you'd use a printf string in other languages.  And Objective-C had stringWithFormat when Java was still on training wheels.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest answer is probably the best here, which is to use `+stringWithFormat:` with an actual multipart format string, instead of separately as you're doing there:

```
Coordinate *coord = [LocationFinder singleton].location.coordinate; // or whatever the type here is
NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude];
```

But in general, your question here is a great example of pointless micro-optimization.

Comment: :):), well I thought since I will be hitting this line every now and then, I am a noob to Obj C anyway.

Comment: so can you elaborate on why is this pointless? this line is not an important line in GPS Coordinate loading?

Comment: @Eddie: For architectural or algorithm decisions, yes, keep performance in mind and do things correctly. But don't micro-optimize.

Comment: @Eddie: Wasting even a few hundred extra cycles when generating coordinates here almost certainly doesn't matter in the slightest. For stuff like this, don't worry about the performance until you've profiled and determined it's actually an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", [LocationFinder    
                            singleton].location.coordinate.latitude, [LocationFinder 
                            singleton].location.coordinate.longitude]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading `latitude` for the longitude value.

To obtain a result like this: `@"40.7,-73.9"` will require setting how many decimal places are formatted for the `float`s.

```
NSString *location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f,%.01f",
                        [LocationFinder singleton].location.coordinate.latitude,
                        [LocationFinder singleton].location.coordinate.longitude];
```